# SEHException when inverting huge matrix

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to calculate mahalanobis distance in c# using emgu cv. I have 3 image each sized 100x100. The step are, first I calculate the covariance matrix, then I calculate the inverse covariance matrix, and last calculate mahalanobis distance with another new image.

But the program throw an SEHException when I calculate the inverse covariance matrix. 
The program running perfectly when I use image that sized 3x3 only. At first i suspect my covariance matrix is too huge (10000x10000) thus the inverse operation fail. But if it was the memory problem it should've thrown an OutOfMemoryException (CMIIW).

The HResult for SEHException is 0x80004005 or HRESULT E_FAIL which is unspecified failure. I dont know how to fix this. Or maybe there's another way to calculate mahalanobis distance safely?

This is my complete code

```
    MySqlConnection SqlCon;
MySqlCommand SqlCmd;
MySqlDataReader SqlDataReader;
string ConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                    "USER=root;";
string CmdString;
string DBString = "TrainingDB";

Image<Gray, Byte>[] TrainingImage100 = new Image<Gray, byte>[3];
Image<Gray, float> covarImage = new Image<Gray, float>(10000, 10000);
Image<Gray, float> invCovarImage = new Image<Gray, float>(10000, 10000);
Image<Gray, float> averageImage = new Image<Gray, float>(100, 100);

SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
try
{
    SqlCon.Open();

    CmdString = "USE `" + DBString + "`";
    SqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, SqlCon);
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    CmdString = "SELECT `face_image` FROM `face100_table` WHERE `person_id` = 1 LIMIT 1";
    SqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, SqlCon);
    SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (SqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        byte[] blob = (byte[])SqlDataReader["face_image"];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        Image<Gray, Byte> tempFrame = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
        TrainingImage100[0] = tempFrame;
        ms.Close();
    }
    SqlDataReader.Close();

    CmdString = "SELECT `face_image` FROM `face100_table` WHERE `person_id` = 2 LIMIT 1";
    SqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, SqlCon);
    SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (SqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        byte[] blob = (byte[])SqlDataReader["face_image"];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        Image<Gray, Byte> tempFrame = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
        TrainingImage100[1] = tempFrame;
        ms.Close();
    }
    SqlDataReader.Close();

    CmdString = "SELECT `face_image` FROM `face100_table` WHERE `person_id` = 3 LIMIT 1";
    SqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, SqlCon);
    SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (SqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        byte[] blob = (byte[])SqlDataReader["face_image"];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        Image<Gray, Byte> tempFrame = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
        TrainingImage100[2] = tempFrame;
        ms.Close();
    }
    SqlDataReader.Close();
}
catch (Exception excpt)
{
    MessageBox.Show("load - " + excpt.Message);
}
SqlCon.Close();

IntPtr[] inObjs = Array.ConvertAll<Image<Gray, byte>, IntPtr>(TrainingImage100, delegate(Image<Gray, byte> img) { return img.Ptr; });

CvInvoke.cvCalcCovarMatrix(inObjs, 3, covarImage, averageImage, COVAR_METHOD.CV_COVAR_NORMAL);
Console.WriteLine(covarImage.Size);
Console.WriteLine(averageImage.Size);

CvInvoke.cvInvert(covarImage, invCovarImage, SOLVE_METHOD.CV_SVD_SYM);
Console.WriteLine(invCovarImage.Size);
```

The error point to method `CvInvoke.cvInvert()` . And for additional information I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and emgu cv version 2.3.0.

Comment: Can you run your program in 64-bit mode? set platform to AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)

Comment: I'm changing the platform to AnyCPU, but still SEHException occured. I cant run it in 64-bit, it says "The assembly to be debugged was built with a platform incompatible with the current system". Is it because i'm using windows xp 32-bit?

Comment: Emgu is a wrapper for native code, the OpenCV library.  Which is why you cannot easily change it to 64-bit mode.  When native code crashes or fails it doesn't usually leave much useful info, like this SEH exception.  Sure, allocating 400 megabytes works once or twice in a 32-bit program, the third time it falls over when it can't find a big enough hole in the address space.

Comment: which means, there's no way this calculation (using CvInvoke.cvInvert() ) can be done in 32-bit program?

Comment: Well, no, it isn't the calculation that's the problem.  It is the size of the matrix.  Use the 64-bit version of Emgu for a quick fix.  Or use smarter code.  http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_2/sidebar.html

Comment: The link that you give is Face Recognition using Euclidan Distance. I've done that, and now i want to improve it using Mahalanobis Distance. In Emgucv Euclidan Distance obtained from calling CvInvoke.cvNorm(). Mahalanobis obtained from calling CvInvoke.cvMahalanobis(). But the inverse covariance matrix for the 3rd parameter isn't available in EigenObjectRecognizer properties. That's why i calculate the inverse covariance matrix again, which is fail. I don't know how else it can be done.
I'll try to change to 64-bit.